# How to change the Cake Console in Ubuntu?

Tags: php, cakephp, console

I have downloaded Cake PHP v2.7.0. Now, I need to change the  console path for baking. What command should I use to change the console from current v1.3.0 to v2.7.0. I tried with the following commands

```
app/Console/cake bake

/var/www/project_name/app/Console/cake.php bake
```

But, still I am not getting updated with the console. I am using ubuntu OS. What command should I try to change the cake console in my system? When I get into the Console folder and execute the command "cake", I get the following warning:

```
PHP Warning:  /usr/share/php/cake/console/templates/skel/tmp/cache/ is not writable in /usr/share/php/cake/libs/cache/file.php on line 281
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/share/php/cake/console/cake.php:0
PHP   2. ShellDispatcher->ShellDispatcher() /usr/share/php/cake/console/cake.php:664
PHP   3. ShellDispatcher->_initEnvironment() /usr/share/php/cake/console/cake.php:136
PHP   4. ShellDispatcher->__bootstrap() /usr/share/php/cake/console/cake.php:176
PHP   5. include_once() /usr/share/php/cake/console/cake.php:272
PHP   6. Cache->config() /usr/share/php/cake/console/templates/skel/config/core.php:304
PHP   7. Cache->_buildEngine() /usr/share/php/cake/libs/cache.php:141
PHP   8. FileEngine->init() /usr/share/php/cake/libs/cache.php:166
PHP   9. FileEngine->__active() /usr/share/php/cake/libs/cache/file.php:94
PHP  10. trigger_error() /usr/share/php/cake/libs/cache/file.php:281

Warning: /usr/share/php/cake/console/templates/skel/tmp/cache/ is not writable in /usr/share/php/cake/libs/cache/file.php on line 281

Call Stack:
    0.0016     380824   1. {main}() /usr/share/php/cake/console/cake.php:0
    0.0174     381144   2. ShellDispatcher->ShellDispatcher() /usr/share/php/cake/console/cake.php:664
    0.1012     535216   3. ShellDispatcher->_initEnvironment() /usr/share/php/cake/console/cake.php:136
    0.1013     538040   4. ShellDispatcher->__bootstrap() /usr/share/php/cake/console/cake.php:176
    0.2275    1716776   5. include_once('/usr/share/php/cake/console/templates/skel/config/core.php') /usr/share/php/cake/console/cake.php:272
    0.2300    1898096   6. Cache->config() /usr/share/php/cake/console/templates/skel/config/core.php:304
    0.2300    1899448   7. Cache->_buildEngine() /usr/share/php/cake/libs/cache.php:141
    0.2340    1956656   8. FileEngine->init() /usr/share/php/cake/libs/cache.php:166
    0.2347    1959744   9. FileEngine->__active() /usr/share/php/cake/libs/cache/file.php:94
    0.2647    2568904  10. trigger_error() /usr/share/php/cake/libs/cache/file.php:281



Welcome to CakePHP v1.3.14 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
Current Paths:
 -app: Console
 -working: /var/www/cakelatest/app/Console
 -root: /var/www/cakelatest/app
 -core: /usr/share/php

Changing Paths:
your working path should be the same as your application path
to change your path use the '-app' param.
Example: -app relative/path/to/myapp or -app /absolute/path/to/myapp

Available Shells:
 acl [CORE]                             i18n [CORE]                            
 api [CORE]                             schema [CORE]                          
 bake [CORE]                            testsuite [CORE]                       
 console [CORE]                         

To run a command, type 'cake shell_name [args]'
To get help on a specific command, type 'cake shell_name help'
```

what am I missing in here?

Comment: Go to directory `project_name/app` and then use `Console/cake` command

Comment: @walkingRed Thanks for your suggestion. When I get into Console/cake, I face the error as shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> PHP Warning:  /usr/share/php/cake/console/templates/skel/tmp/cache/ is not writable in /usr/share/php/cake/libs/cache/file.php on line 281

Sounds like a permission Problem to me.

can you print here the output of

```
ls -la /usr/share/php/cake/console/templates/skel/tmp/cache | grep -e " \.$"
```

Comment: @CansanCity Here is the output I've got with your command: 
"drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jul 15  2013 ."

Comment: so it IS a permission Problem. After running "sudo chown youruser:youruser /usr/share/php/cake/console/templates/skel/tmp/cache" everthing should be fine

Answer (score 0):

When you open the app in the web, cakephp change the `/APP/tmp/` folder, you need run the cake command with the `www-data` user, you can use this command:

```
 sudo www-data php Console/cake.php bake
```

Comment: You've answered the question after 4 years. Thank you.